# DB connection lost during a transaction

Tags: java, mysql, transactions, innodb

I have a JDBC transaction that updates multiple rows. In middle of transaction  database connection is lost. And then the transaction cannot rollback or commit as db connection is lost.

Following are the DB/ tx details.

- DB: MYSQL
- Storage engine: Inno DB
- Transaction Isolation: Repeatable Reads

When this happens the locks taken by the transaction still there in the DB.

Following is the output of "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;" command.

---TRANSACTION 69476, ACTIVE 5395 sec
96 lock struct(s), heap size 24784, 301 row lock(s), undo log entries 301

1. Is there a way that we can manually remove the locks?
2. Can we change the time max transaction or lock time specified?
3. What is the best way to handle this situation

EDIT: 
Following are the code snippets

---

```
 Ebean.beginTransaction(TxIsolation.REPEATABLE_READ);

    boolean foundError = false;

    for (Object object : objectList) {
            if (!saveObject(object)) {
                foundError = true;
                break;
            }
    }

    if (foundError) {
        Ebean.endTransaction();
    } else {
        Ebean.commitTransaction();
    }
```

---

---

```
  public boolean saveObject(Object object)  {
        try {
            Ebean.save(object);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

---

Comment: How are you handling the transaction in Java? Please include the code in your answer.

Comment: Added code snippets

Comment: I would expect it to quickly discover that the client is gone and do a `ROLLBACK`, thereby freeing the locks.  Did it?